# How to remove a string with sed based on a variable with line breaks?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using the following bash script of which the goal is to *remove the headers from Go files*.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add header to files
HEADER=$(cat header.txt)

# loop over all go files
for i in $(find . -name \*.go); do
    # If present, remove it
    if fgrep -q "$HEADER" $i; then
        # remove the header
        sed -e "s/$HEADER/g" $i # <== THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG        
    fi
done
```

This however results in:

`unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`

I've tried escaping with:

```
HEADER_ESCAPED="${HEADER@Q}"
echo $HEADER_ESCAPED
```

Which in turn results in:

`header.sh: line 10: ${HEADER@Q}: bad substitution`

How can I properly format / escape the variable to replace the header including its linebreaks?

Comment: syntax for substitute command is `s/search/replace/flags` ... you are missing replace section.. if your intention is to delete entire line, use `/search/d`.. for ex: `seq 5 | sed '/[24]/d'`

Comment: use https://www.shellcheck.net/ for some improvement/potential-issues/etc ... see also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, is `/d` also global?

Comment: `d` deletes entire line, it is a different command than substitute.. use `s/search//g` if you wish to only delete all matching portions from a line

Comment: You need `bash 4.4` or newer in order to use `${HEADER@Q}` btw.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `sed` is fundamentally a line-oriented tool, and it can't substitute across line endings.

If you really want to use `sed` and your header has unique first and last lines and you don't care too much about the middle, you could use something like

```
sed '/first line/,/last line/d' $i
```

If you really want to do a substitution on the entire header, try using Perl, which can cope with line ends in substitutions if you use the `s` modifier.

```
perl -e '$_ = join("", <>); s/'"$HEADER"'//s; print' $i
```

Note that this is going to have problems if `$HEADER` contains `bash` or Perl metacharacters. Over to you to sort out the quoting for that!